# Background behind Eichler's discovery of the relationship of a modular form with an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, galois-representations, automorphic-forms

In Fraenkel's Love and Math (and Richard Taylor's Modular Arithmetic IAS Post https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2012/taylor-modular-arithmetic), specifically in Chapter 8 Magic Numbers, page 88., Fraenkel mentions that Eichler was the first to discover the relationship between (number of solutions of) elliptic curves and (coefficients of Fourier expansions of)  modular forms. He shows the concrete example that Eichler worked out.

Anyone has the reference where Eichler showed this example? I have his 1954 paper "Quaternäre quadratische Formen und die Riemannsche Vermutung fÜr die Kongruenzzetafunktion", but I don't understand german and the example doesn't seem to be stated there, at least explicitely.

And more interestingly, does anyone has any idea of how Eichler arrived at this discovery? Was there anything similar observed before? (specially considering infinite sequence of arithmetical information)

Comment: I see you're a member of the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE site. Did you consider if questions like yours here might be a better fit on that site instead?

Comment: Do you mean like proving that for $f$ an eigenform with rational coefficients $\in S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ then $F(\tau)=\int_{i\infty}^\tau 2i\pi f(z)dz$ is analytic from $X_0(N)$ to a complex torus (and is also a morphism of algebraic variety defined over $\Bbb{Q}$) ? Yes it is plausible that it wasn't known to Jacobi, Hecke, Ramanujan, Artin and so on.

Comment: In the simplest weight 2 cusp forms there are the ones coming from Hecke L-functions of grossencharacters associated to CM elliptic curves ($y^2=x^3+x$ is defined over $\Bbb{Q}$). There is also this non CM [eta product](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/11/2/a/a/)

Comment: @reuns: do those weight 2 cusp forms also have numbers derived from the number of solutions of their associated CM elliptic curves (mod p), as coefficients of their Fourier expansions?

Comment: Yes, once you know the morphism to the elliptic curve then deriving the [Eichler-Shimura relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eichler%E2%80%93Shimura_congruence_relation) and the correspondence of L-functions is not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert in these questions, but here are the results of my search through much of the relevant literature. The connection between the number of points on elliptic curves over finite fields and certain analytic functions was known before Eichler in the case of elliptic curves with complex multiplication (see Davenport and Hasse, Die Nullstellen der Kongruenzzetafunktionen (1935) for some classical examples). To the best of my knowldge there are no explicit examples in Eichler's articles; such examples became fashionable (and indispensible) later when Serre and Swinnerton-Dyer dreamed up connections between congruences of the Ramanujan tau function and Galois representations. Shimura discusses the explicit example
$$ x^2 = 4x^3 - \frac{4 \cdot 31}{3}x - \frac{41 \cdot 61}{27} $$
in his 1966 article "A reciprocity law in non-solvable extensions", and apparently Tate pointed out that this curve is isogeneous to the famous elliptic curve $y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2$ mentioned by Fraenkel.